# HPE 5820X Configure L3 Routing

Tags: routing, hp, switch

I'm having some trouble configuring L3 routing on HPE 5820X. This is the first HPE switch I've worked with and would like some pointers on the commands to get this working. So far I have configured all the VLANs and created VLAN interfaces for each. However, if I assign a port to a VLAN and connect a device to it, I can see that it is creating the static routes as L2 only. How exactly can I get it to route between the VLANs?

**Current Configuration**

```
vlan 1
#
vlan 10
 description Server Network
#
vlan 20
 description User Network
#
vlan 30
 description Guest Network
#
vlan 50
 description Camera Network
#
vlan 70
 description Misc Network
#
vlan 100
 description Switch Network
#
vlan 110
 description Management Network
#
vlan 200
 description vMotion Network
#
interface NULL0
#
interface Vlan-interface10
 ip address 10.64.10.1 255.255.255.0
#
interface Vlan-interface20
 ip address 10.64.20.1 255.255.255.0
#
interface Vlan-interface30
  ---- More ----
 ip address 10.64.30.1 255.255.255.0
#
interface Vlan-interface50
 ip address 10.64.50.1 255.255.255.0
#
interface Vlan-interface70
 ip address 10.64.70.1 255.255.255.0
#
interface Vlan-interface100
 ip address 10.64.100.2 255.255.255.0
#
interface Vlan-interface110
 ip address 10.64.110.1 255.255.255.0
#
interface Vlan-interface200
 ip address 10.64.200.1 255.255.255.0
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/25
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 100
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/26
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 20
```

**Routes**

```
display ip routing-table
Routing Tables: Public
        Destinations : 4        Routes : 4

Destination/Mask    Proto  Pre  Cost         NextHop         Interface

10.64.20.0/24       Direct 0    0            10.64.20.1      Vlan20
10.64.20.1/32       Direct 0    0            127.0.0.1       InLoop0
127.0.0.0/8         Direct 0    0            127.0.0.1       InLoop0
127.0.0.1/32        Direct 0    0            127.0.0.1       InLoop0
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Looks like all it needed were devices to be plugged into ports that belong to respective VLANs for the switch to online that VLAN and virtual interface.